# Linear independence of a set.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone explain me what does it mean for a vector $v$ to be (linearly) independent of a set $S$?

Here, $S$ is a set of vectors.

From my point of view, it is just the other way of saying that $v$ is independent of any vector $x \in S$.

Now I wonder if I am right...

Comment: Linear independence of a set does not imply only pairwise independence with each element of the set.

Comment: It means that there is no (finite) combination of vectors in $S$ that add together to become $v$, even if you allow scaling the vectors of $S$ by arbitrary scalars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $v$ is linearly independent from the the set of vectors $S$ iff $v$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination  of vectors in $S$. This is more than to say that any couple $\{v,x\}$ with $x \in S$ is linearly independent.